# rails setting form action route dynamically via collection select

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I've got a polymorphic association for `group_invitations`. You can invite users to join `product` as a member or to join `product_customer` (it's not user, it's something like product customer case) as a customer. To be able to join they have to accept the invitation.

Since it's polymorphic I decided to do the create action with more controllers instead of using hidden fields. Thanks to that route actions look like:

```
products/1/group_invitations
product_customers/1/group_invitations
```

My problem is that I render all the forms on the product show page. So it's easy to render the form for the certain product like:

```
<%= form_for([@product, GroupInvitation.new]) do %>
..........
```

But I'm stuck with the product_customer. Since `product has_many product_customers` (again it's not the user but the "product customer case"), user should choose the `product_customer` instance with collection select and rails should set the form action route based on that. How can I achieve that? Is there a rails way to set it somehow or I gotta use js/jquery?

```
<%= form_for( #should be set based on collection select ) do %>

  <%= f.collection_select(:product_customer_id, @product.product_customers, :id, :name) %>
```

TL;DR Rest of the code is provided just to show how controllers/routes look like. According to me not necessary to solve the problem.

routes.rb

```
resources :group_invitations, only: :destroy do
  member do
    patch :accept
  end
end

resources :products do
  resources :group_invitations, only: [:new, :create], module: :products
end

resources :product_customers do
  resources :group_invitations, only: [:new, :create], module: :product_customers
end
```

products/group_invitations_controller

```
class Products::GroupInvitationsController < GroupInvitationsController
  before_action :set_group_invitable

  private

    def set_group_invitable
      @group_invitable = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    end
end
```

product_customers/group_invitations_controller

```
class ProductCustomers::GroupInvitationsController < GroupInvitationsController
  before_action :set_group_invitable

  private

    def set_group_invitable
      @group_invitable = ProductCustomer.find(params[:product_customer_id])
    end
end
```

controllers/group_invitations_controller.rb

```
def create
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @group_invitation = @group_invitable.group_invitations.new(group_invitations_params)
  @group_invitation.sender = @product.owner
  @group_invitation.recipient = @recipient
  if @group_invitation.save
    .........
```

Comment: so you want the route and action on your form to change (be set) only when the user has selected from a dropdown in the form itself?

Comment: If you have a better idea, you can tell me that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

There is always a value selected in the collection select. On loading the page it's set to the first item. So if the user doesn't change it then it will be saved with that.

```
<%= form_for([@product_customers.first, GroupInvitation.new]) do |f| %>
```

If the user starts playing with the collection select then it changes the route with jquery.

```
$(document).on('change', '#product-customer-collection-select', function () {
  var newRouteId = $(this).val();
  var newActionURL = "/product_customers/" + newRouteId + "/group_invitations";
  $(this).closest("form").attr("action", newActionURL);
});
```